# ASP.NET Multiple Values to a Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a hard time adding a 2nd field to my cookie for some odd reason I can't seem to figure it out. What I am trying to do is have a page that you enter a First name and Last name into it, and then when you click continue it stores those 2 into a cookie, then it redirects to Order page that says "Welcome back Mercenary". Now on order page I have a button that goes back to original page with the 2 name text boxes. I wish for those to be populated with the previous data, and if I change it to have it update the 2nd page with the changes. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        DateTime expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        this.SetResponseCookie("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text, expiry);
        this.SetResponseCookie("LastName", txtLastName.Text, expiry);
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx");
}
private void SetResponseCookie(string name, string value,
                               DateTime expiry)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cookie.Values.Add("LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    cookie.Expires = expiry;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        if (!(Request.Cookies["FirstName"] == null))
            txtFirstName.Text = Request.Cookies["FirstName"].Value;
    if (!IsPostBack)
        if (!(Request.Cookies["LastName"] == null))
            txtLastName.Text = Request.Cookies["LastName"].Value;
}
```

Right now, once I hit continue it goes to the Order page with "Welcome back Mercenary&LastName=One!" and if I tell it to go back to the first page it fills it with "Mercenary&LastName=One"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you going back by the browser or navigating by a button?

Comment: navigating by a button.

Comment: then why don't you just clear the cookies before navigating back? this is what you want right?

Comment: What I want is once FirstName and LastName is entered it goes to the Order Page, on Order Page there is a button to go back. When I go back I want it to display the information that was previously put in there. Right now I can get the FirstName to populate just fine, I am having issues with the cookie properly adding the LastName.

Comment: why don't you use session to achieve this?

Comment: This is part of my school project, I have to use session, cookies, cache, and application state. So far I only figured out the Application State part of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

its working fine with me, and get the value by by this,

```
 string Name = Request.Cookies["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
```